# Quasiquotes for multiple parameters and parameter lists

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

[Quasiquotes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/quasiquotes.html) are amazing—they make writing macros in Scala hugely less painful, and in my experience they almost always just work exactly as I'd expect. And best of all, they're now available [as a plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) in Scala 2.10.

This question is about a small problem that I ran into while writing [this blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/30/horrible-code/). It's on my list of stuff to look into when I can find a few minutes, but I figured I'd post it here in case someone else can beat me to it, and to help other people who are running into the same question.

Suppose I have a list of lists of name-type pairs:

```
val pss = List(
  List(newTermName("x") -> typeOf[Int], newTermName("y") -> typeOf[Char]),
  List(newTermName("z") -> typeOf[String])
)
```

I want to turn these into a tree that looks like this:

```
def foo(x: Int, y: Char)(z: String) = ???
```

The following works just fine:

```
q"def bar(${pss.head.head._1}: ${pss.head.head._2}) = ???"
```

That is, it builds the following tree:

```
def bar(x: Int) = ???
```

Which suggests that I should be able to write something like this:

```
val quoted = pss.map(_.map { case (n, t) => q"$n: $t" })

q"def foo..${quoted.map(ps => q"($ps)")} = 1"
```

Or a little more simply, with multiple parameters in a single parameter list:

```
q"def baz(..${quoted.head}) = ???"
```

Neither works—I get errors like this:

```
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[c.universe.Typed]
 required: List[c.universe.ValDef]
           q"def baz(..${quoted.head}) = ???"
                                ^
```

Fair enough—I can see how it would look to the quasiquoter like I'm building typed expressions rather than defining parameters in `quoted`. None of the obvious things I could think to try worked (adding `= _`, explicitly typing the quasiquote as a `ValDef`, etc.).

I know that I can build the parameter definitions manually:

```
val valDefs = pss.map(
  _.map {
    case (n, t) => ValDef(Modifiers(Flag.PARAM), n, TypeTree(t), EmptyTree)
  }
)
```

And now the `baz` version (with one parameter list) works:

```
q"def baz(..${valDefs.head}) = ???"
```

But not the `foo` version (the one with multiple parameter lists).

So there are two questions here. First, how can I use quasiquotes to turn a name-type pair into a parameter `ValDef` outside of the context of a quoted parameter list? And second, how can I turn a list of lists of parameter definitions into multiple parameter lists?

It's easy enough to fall back to manual AST construction for the whole damn thing (see [my post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/30/horrible-code/) for an example), but I'd like to be able to use quasiquotes instead.

Comment: 1) I believe q"val $n: $t" will work 2) Use ...$ to splice lists of lists

Comment: `val` works perfectly here—thanks! `...$quoted` doesn't, though—I'd guess because the inner lists aren't automatically lifted to parameter lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the quick solution to your problem:

```
val pss = List(
  List(newTermName("x") -> typeOf[Int], newTermName("y") -> typeOf[Char]),
  List(newTermName("z") -> typeOf[String])
)
val vparamss: List[List[ValDef]] = pss.map { _.map { case (name, tpe) => q"val $name: $tpe" } }
q"def foo(...$vparamss)"
```

As you can see special ...$splice lets you define a function with multiple argument lists. Function arguments themselves are represented in the same manner as regular vals.

Another example where ...$it might be useful:

```
val xy = List(List(q"x"), List(q"y"))
q"f(...$xy)" // same as q"f(x)(y)"
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I didn't think to try putting the list of parameter lists in parentheses, but I can see that it makes sense to use that as the syntax here.