# Matching function literals with quasiquotes in Scala

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

This question is similar in motivation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18559559/334519) (although it's about a problem I ran into in a [different context](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/31/feeding-our-vampires/)).

I can pattern match on a function literal pretty easily without quasiquotes:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object QQExample {
  def funcDemo(f: Int => String) = macro funcDemo_impl
  def funcDemo_impl(c: Context)(f: c.Expr[Int => String]) = {
    import c.universe._

    f.tree match {
      case Function(ps, body) => List(ps, body) foreach println
      case _ => c.abort(
        c.enclosingPosition,
        "Must provide a function literal."
      )
    }

    c.literalUnit
  }
}
```

Which works like this:

```
scala> QQExample.funcDemo((a: Int) => a.toString)
List(val a: Int = _)
a.toString()
```

Now suppose I want to use quasiquotes to do the same kind of match more flexibly. The following will also match on that function, and prints what we'd expect.

```
case q"($x: $t) => $body" => List(x, t, body) foreach println
```

But if I want to specify the type in the pattern, it doesn't match:

```
case q"($x: Int) => $body" => List(x, body) foreach println
```

And none of the following even compile:

```
case q"$p => $body"      => List(p,  body) foreach println
case q"($p) => $body"    => List(p,  body) foreach println
case q"..$ps => $body"   => List(ps, body) foreach println
case q"(..$ps) => $body" => List(ps, body) foreach println
```

Is it possible to specify the type of a parameter when matching on a function literal with quasiquotes, or to match on an unknown number of parameters?

Comment: That's a bug. All of the patterns in your last code block should work for single-argument anonymous functions. Follow [SI-7803](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7803) to get notified when the fix is merged into master

Comment: The fix is sitting in the 2.11 pull requests queue. After it's merged I'll backport it to 2.10.

I was also a bit wrong with saying that all patterns will work. You'll have to use parentheses over arguments (i.e. patterns 2 and 4)

Comment: @DenShabalin Should matching against function types work as well? I successfully matched as follows `val q"Capture.capture[$tp]" = tree` with tree as `capture[() => R]`, `capture[A => R]`, `capture[(A, B) => R]`, etc. Next I am failed to match `val tq"(..$ts) => $tr" = tp`. Please, give a hint on how it should be done.

Comment: @DenShabalin: shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: Matching against function literals and functions types should work in 2.11.x but might not work via paradise plugin for 2.10 atm. There is a plan to backport latest quasiquotes to paradise plugin around 2.11 release.

Comment: @DenShabalin because if it's an answer, then this won't top the unanswered questions list for scala.  It doesn't have to be a pleasant answer, or even the correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With latest paradise plugin for 2.10 and in vanilla 2.11 you can do it this way:

```
val q"(..$args) => $body" = f.tree
```

I've just tested it out with [paradise example project](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise) with following `Macros.scala`:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object Macro {
  def apply(f: Any): Any = macro impl
  def impl(c: Context)(f: c.Expr[Any]) = { import c.universe._
    val q"(..$args) => $body" = f.tree
    println(s"args = $args, body = $body")
    c.Expr(q"()")
  }
}
```

And `Test.scala`:

```
object Test extends App {
  Macro((x: Int) => x + 1)
}
```

You can read in more about handling of function trees with quasiquotes in [corresponding chapter of quasiquote guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/expression-details.html#function).